# Permissions to move files and folders

Tags: server

Good day Peeps,

I have two user accounts to my samba server - dpuser & dpuser1.

Dpuser1 should have the highest level of access in this case,
and dpuser should have limited directory access.

The problem is, dpuser creates a folder with files in it, the dpuser1 can't move delete or edit any of those files, but they can view it.

I can't run `sudo chmod 777 /home/srv -R` every time someone creates a folder and/or files from the dpuser account.

Any ideas? If dpuser creates a file/folder that both accounts have permission to, to chop and change the files/folders?

My smb.conf file:

[Master Drive]

```
    comment = Mater drive files
    path = /home/srv/master
    browseable = yes
    read only = no
    #guest ok = yes
    valid users = dpuser dpuser1
    writeable = yes
    directory mask = 0777
    create mask = 0777
    write list = dpuser dpuser1
```

[Accounts]

```
    comment = Accounts Files
    path = /home/srv/accounts
    browseable = yes
    read only = no
    #guest ok = yes
    valid users = dpuser1
    create mask = 0777
```